# Removing software that came from a pkg file?

Tags: macos

I can't find the uninstaller. I installed some service using a pkg file and now I want to get rid of it. How do I do that? I would prefer not to use lsbom and rm and stuff. It looks scary.

Answer (score 5):

Not a direct answer to your question, but you can also use "Suspicious Package", a QuickLook plug-in for Finder, to see what files a package installed: http://www.mothersruin.com/software/SuspiciousPackage/

Depending on what files were installed where, you may be able to find them in Finder and drag to the trash; otherwise you may have to go into Terminal and rm around.

Comment: Tx. Helps prevention. Though a remedy would be nice.

Answer (score 3):

For the most part, Mac applications don't have uninstallers because they're rarely needed. You can almost always just toss the undesired offender into your trash.

Comment: After downvoting an answer, it's considered polite to say why in a comment.

Comment: Agreed (I didn’t do it)

Comment: I disagree. After much digging I found this package installed a service and a launchagent. The service was eating CPU and memory at login. I had to manually remove them.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you try something like [AppZapper](http://www.appzapper.com/) ($) or 
[AppCleaner](http://www.freemacsoft.net/AppCleaner/index.php) (Freeware). There are others that work similarly.

Comment: Neither of them have a pkg removal option that I can find...